# Excel C# pivotTable refresh

Tags: c#, interop

I am trying to refresh a pivot table from C# code and than refresh the charts that are based on that pivot table. I have ran my code several times up to a point that every run I get the following error:
"Please wait until Microsoft Excel has finished refreshing the PivotTable report, and then try the command again."

In addition, one of the pivottalbes connection throws and exception that it was deleted when trying to refresh although it is there in the file.

Any ideas on how to resolve This?

Thank you